# Returning reference from overloaded operatora and expression with temporary objects

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, temporary

I am playing around with C++ to remind myself about it. So I experimented with operator + overloading returning reference. Motive for this is to avoid unnecessary copying of objects. Look at the example. I created class String and concatenated strings with +. It was just experimental so you'll notice some ugly stuff as public attributes.

Here are relevant parts of the code.

String.hpp

```
#ifndef STRING_HPP_
#define STRING_HPP_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef CPP11
    typedef wchar_t unicode16;
#else
    typedef char16_t unicode16;
#endif //CPP11

class String {

    unicode16 * value;
    unsigned strLength;

    void initEmpty() {
        value = 0L;
        strLength = 0;
    }

    static unsigned counter;
public:

    static String ** trash;

    unsigned id;

    String::String() : value(0L), strLength(0){
        id=counter++;
        trash[id]=this;
        cout << "Creating empty: " << id << "\n";
    }

    String::String(const String &str);

    String(const char *);

    String(const unicode16 *);

    unsigned length() const {
        return strLength;
    }

    ~String() {

        wcout << L"Deleting " << id << ": " << value << L"\n";
        trash[id]=0L;
        delete value;
    }

    String & operator +(String &);

    unicode16 * getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};

#endif /* STRING_HPP_ */
```

String.cpp

```
#include "String.hpp"
#include "../exception/IllegalArgumentException.h"
#include <string.h>


unsigned String::counter = 0;

String ** String::trash = new String *[100]();

String::String(const String & str) {
    value = new unicode16[str.strLength + 1];
    strLength = str.strLength;
    for(int i = 0; i < strLength ; i++) {
        value[i] = str.value[i];
    }
    value[strLength] = 0;
    id = counter++;trash[id]=this;
    wcout << L"Created (copy): " << id << ": " << value << L"\n";
}

String::String(const char *charArray) {
    if (charArray == 0L) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Char array pointer is null");
    }
    strLength = strlen(charArray);
    value = new unicode16[strLength + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        value[i] = (unicode16)charArray[i];
    }
    value[strLength] = 0;
    id = counter++;trash[id]=this;
    wcout << L"Created (char *): " << id << ": " << value << L"\n";
}

String::String(const unicode16 *utfArray) {
    if (utfArray == 0L) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unicode array pointer is null");
    }
    strLength = wcslen(utfArray);
    value = new unicode16[strLength + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        value[i] = utfArray[i];
    }
    value[strLength] = 0;
    id = counter++;
    trash[id]=this;
    wcout << L"Created (unicode): " << id << ": " << value << L"\n";
}

String & String::operator +(String &str) {
    unsigned newLength = length() + str.length();
    unicode16 * newArray = new unicode16[newLength + 1];
    wcscpy(newArray, value);
    wcscpy(newArray + strLength, str.value);

    String * strPointer = new String();
    strPointer->value = newArray;
    strPointer->strLength = newLength;

    String &result = *strPointer;
    wcout << L"Empty loaded: " << result.id << ": " << result.value << L"\n";
    return result;
}
```

And the main method

```
#include "../string/string.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int metodica(void) {
    String & please = String("Please");
    String meString = "me";
    String & me = meString;
    String & delStrRef = String(" delete ");

    String & result1 = please + delStrRef + me;

    wcout << result1.getValue() << L"\n";
    delete &result1;
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    metodica();
    cout << "These are not deleted\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (String::trash[i] != 0L) {
            wcout << String::trash[i]->getValue() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Executing this in CDT using VS2010 compiler and linker i got following output

Created (char *): 0: Please

Created (char *): 1: me

Created (char *): 2:  delete

Creating empty: 3

Empty loaded: 3: Please delete

Creating empty: 4

Empty loaded: 4: Please delete me

Please delete me

Deleting 4: Please delete me

Deleting 2:  delete

Deleting 1: me

Deleting 0: Please

These are not deleted

Please delete

The question is why temporary object created in the expression please + delStrRef + me; is not deleted. Shouldn't it get deleted at the end of the expression or it goes differently if reference is temporary object and not the object itself.

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics), then stop writing ugly code.  You're not saving yourself anything.

Comment: It was intentionally ugly because I wanted to quickly see what is actually done with temporary objects. This is certainly not for production or anything serious.

Comment: But anyway thanks for the articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String & String::operator +(String &str) {
    ...
    String * strPointer = new String();
    ...
    String &result = *strPointer;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

You manually created the object, and then returned the reference to it. Hence, the compiler did not insert `delete` operator. So, you cannot return reference without memory leak and manually destroing the object.

For example in `Qt` library `operator+` implemented as

```
Q_EXPORT inline const QString operator+( const QString &s1, const QString &s2 ) {
    QString tmp( s1 );
    tmp += s2;
    return tmp; 
}
```

Where `operator+=` declared as `QString    &operator+=( const QString &str );`